# How to center bootstrap column elements vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have the following structure:

```
 <div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Content</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I want a column, that acts as a container, and leaves 2 units on every side, hence the col-md-8 div. I want that centered, and I want all the other column elements centered too, but I don't know how to do this. Adding margins doesn't work as it should, for some reason. Adding "align: center" centers the text inside the columns, I don't want that. Can someone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `col-<size>-offset-<number>` tag to shift the elements by that respective amount:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">Content</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">Content</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Check out the Bootstrap page on CSS styling, they have some examples that may help you understand how offset and nesting div's works: [Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

[Here is a Plunkr demonstrating some ways to use nesting and offsets](https://embed.plnkr.co/ryydStH4XIZvJC0p71Jn/)

Comment: Big thanks man. You saved me a load of time doing stupid things to achieve the same result.

Comment: @MihailIvanchev No problem :) glad I could help. Don't forget to mark the answer if it solved the problem!

Comment: Yeah, there is a time that has to pass before I could do that. I marked it :)

Comment: @MihailIvanchev I created a Plunkr that you can check out also, it may help

Answer (score 0):

use this .center-container css to each element to center your div element.

```css
    .center-container{
        display: table;
        margin: 0 auto;
        float: none;
    }
        <div class="col-md-8 center-container">
          <div class="col-md-12 center-container">
            <div class="col-md-6">Content</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">Content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
```